# Migrating custom Legacy PHP web applications to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, legacy-code

I'm trying to follow this guide to [Migrating Legacy Web Applications to Laravel](https://www.phparch.com/2019/03/migrating-legacy-web-applications-to-laravel/).

This is my situation:

I've 2 web application under the same host, both written in PHP

- one (the legacy) is a "custom framework"
- second is a Laravel 5.4 application

My goal is to serve both the application only under Laravel app, so my unique entry point for the application is the `index.php` from the Laravel.

As you can read in the article, I'm trying to start the legacy app inside the Laravel `App\Exceptions\Handler`

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception) {
   if( $exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException ) {
      // pass to legacy framework - contents of index.php
      die();
   }
}
```

when the legacy route is not found.

I've created my own `App\Providers\LegacyServiceProvider`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class LegacyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton("LegacyApp", function ($app){
            require_once base_path("legacy/index.php");
            return;
        });
    }
}
```

addend in the `config/app.php` laravel configuration file

```php
    // other providers
    App\Providers\LegacyServiceProvider::class,
```

and now comes the fun part... This is the `index.php` of the **legacy app**

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ ."/app/config/conf.php";

$oSession = new Session();
$oDb = new DbMedoo();
$dbCon = $oDb->dbConn();

include __DIR__ . '/app/routes.php';
```

`app/config/conf.php`

```php
<?php

// Some definitions here

// ROUTING
$router = new AltoRouter();

// TWIG
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(SITE_CONFIG_DIR . "../../src/App/views");

// Other stuff here
```

the `app/routes.php` file

```php
<?php
// **************************************************
// ****************    AltoRouter   *****************
// **************************************************

$router->map( 'GET|POST', '/', 'home.php', 'home');

// Some other legacy routes here
```

and finally a simple `home.php` "controller"

```php
<?php

// Some initial checks here

$someModelClass = new SomeModelClass();
$anotherModelClass = new AnotherModelClass();

// some other logics here

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('home.twig');

echo $template->render(array(
    'someVariables' => $someVariableToPass,
));
```

As you can see I've no Class!!

**END OF STORY!**

So, when i try to run the legacy app in the `App\Exception\Handler`

```php
if( $exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException ) {
    // pass to legacy framework
    app()->make("LegacyApp");
    die(); // prevent Laravel sending a 404 response
}
```

This error fittingly appears

```
(1/1) ReflectionException
Class LegacyApp does not exist
```

**Suggestions are welcomed**

Someone with the same situation here? How I could do this without refactor the entire codebase?

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you *can't.*  And don't use the word, "refactor."  Use the word, *"rewrite."*  Because that's what you would be doing to an application that right now is running and moving the freight even though it's not in "Laravel."

I would predict that the financial justification is almost certainly not there.

Comment: I agree. This is my legacy and I can't figure out how to dismiss without loosing our mind.